# Reference request on connection between PDE problems

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, hyperbolic-pde, cauchy-problem

I am trying to find references in the literature that connect solutions of any two of the problems given bellow. I study deterministic and stochastic conservation laws. Problems that I am interested in are:

Deterministic Cauchy problem: $\hspace{1cm} (1) \hspace{1cm}    \begin{cases}
u_t+f(u)_x=0 \\[2ex] 
u(x,0)=u_0 (x)
\end{cases}
$

Deterministic Riemann problem: $\hspace{1cm}  (2) \hspace{1cm}    \begin{cases}
u_t+f(u)_x=0 \\[2ex] 
u(x,0)= \begin{cases}
u_l, x<0 \\[2ex]
u_r, x\geq0
\end{cases}
\end{cases}
$

Stochastic Riemann problem: $\hspace{1cm} (3) \hspace{1cm}    \begin{cases}
u_t+f(u)_x=g(u)W(t) \\[2ex] 
u(x,0)= \begin{cases}
u_l, x<0 \\[2ex]
u_r, x\geq0
\end{cases}
\end{cases}
$

Stochastic Cauchy problem: $\hspace{1cm} (4) \hspace{1cm}    \begin{cases}
u_t+f(u)_x=g(u)W(t) \\[2ex] 
u(x,0)=u_0 (x)
\end{cases}
$

Here u $\in  \mathbb{R}^n$ and W(t) is a white noise. For $n=1$ we have one equation and for $n>1$ we have system of conservation laws. Function $g$ depends of $u$ so we say that we have multiplicative noise.

So far I only have found two references that study connection between solutions of problems (1) and (2). Those are:

1. TP Liu, Large-Time Behavior of Solutions of Initial and Initial-Boundary Value Problems of a General System of Hyperbolic Conservation Laws, Comm. Math. Phys. Volume 55, Number 2 (1977), 163-177; [projecteuclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103900984), [DOI: 10.1007/BF01626518](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01626518).
2. L. Hsiao, Quasilinear hyperbolic systems and dissipative mechanisms, World Scientific Publishing, 1997  -  Chapter 5.

Anyone know any reference that connects any other pair of problems?